# Compare CSV file data using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, diff

I want to **compare the data** in two .csv files.Have to compare the updated data between these two .csv file using nodejs.
Is ther any possibilities to do it in Nodejs.
Thanks,I am very newbie to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easiest using one of the following modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsv

or other that you find in:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/csv
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/tsv

(don't worry if it's CSV or TSV - just make sure that you use the correct delimiter which is comma in your case).